# mysql and mysql2 not working inside Fission runtime

Tags: mysql, node.js, kubernetes-fission

I tried to create my own Fission NodeJS runtime image, I tried to install mysql and mysql2 npm packages.
My docker file is using node:8-alpine base image.

But always when running a function I am getting the following error

```
user code load error: Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
```

I tried to install mysql and mysql2 globally inside my DockerFile, but still without any luck

```
RUN npm install -g mysql
RUN npm install -g mysql2
```

I am always updating the environment using the next command:

```
fission env update --name nodejs --image mindbehind.azurecr.io/fission/nodejs-env
```

But even I tried to remove all functions and all environments and re-install from scratch the new environment and my function.
I already installed other libraries before so I am sure that I could update the Fission NodeJS environment.

I could not understand why is that, anyone has experienced that before and could solve it?

Comment: I've a similar problem with python env. Did you solve your problem? If yes, can you give me some hints?

Comment: it appeared to me that I need to remove the environment and create it again, and it would help if you change the image name or but a tag for it, mostly the image is cached without doing that